# Change DIV id with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to change the div id="test" to the value from the dropdown option selected using javascript. I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdskX/7/) started. If user selects 2013 then the div id="test" should change to div id="2013" and show the second dropdown of months. The value from the year dropdown will ultimately be used to query the database for the actual months recorded in that year but for now I'm interested in changing the div id and storing the value for later use.

```
<div class="report_select" id="style_container_div">
    <label>Year:</label>
    <select size="1" id="year" title="" type="select" name="style">
        <option value="">Select Year</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
    </select>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="error-message-style"></div>
</div>
<div id="test" class="style-sub-1" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
    <label>Select a Month:</label>
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="February">February</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
        <option value="April">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="August">August</option>
        <option value="September">September</option>
        <option value="October">October</option>
        <option value="November">November</option>
        <option value="December">December</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#year").change(function () {
    var targID = $(this).val();
    $("div.style-sub-1").hide();
    $('#' + targID).show();

})

$("div.style-sub-1 select").change ( function () {
    $("div.style-sub-2").hide ();
    document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("id", targID);
    $('#' + targID).show ();
} )
    </script>
```

Comment: You should not change id of elements, instead use data-id="your-value".

Comment: If you create an id for an element, it should not be changed at runtime. agree with @FaisalSayed.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you use jQuery instead of `document.getElementById("id")` you can do simply `$("#id")`, and instead of `.setAttribute` you can do `.attr('attr', 'attrVal')`.

Because the id of `$("#test")` will be changed a solution would be to change the id of `select` parent.

```
// on change
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().attr("id", $this.val());
```

But instead of changing the id, I recommend you to use a `data-attr`.

```
<div id="test" data-value="test">...</div>
```

And then to set it:

```
$("#test").attr("data-value", $this.val());
```

Comment: @Johnツ I tried `$this.val()` got an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined` it should be like `$(this).val()` so edited your answer

Comment: @user1671639 You see, I've declared it: `var $this = $(this)` to prevent calling `$(this)` again, and again.

Answer (score 0):

`targID` there is no variable in this method.

```
$("div.style-sub-1 select").change ( function () {
    $("div.style-sub-2").hide ();
    document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("id", targID); //  error
    $('#' + targID).show ();
});
```

from your code, it seems you're already using using `jQuery` therefore try it in

```
$('#test').prop("id","yourId");
```

Answer (score 0):

I [updated your JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdskX/11/). I changed your Javascript to reflect the following:

```
$("select#year").on('change', function () {
    var targID = $(this).val();
    $("div.style-sub-1").hide();
    $('#' + targID).show();
})

$("select#year").on('change', function () {
    var tarID  = $(this).val();
    $('#test').attr('id', tarID); // document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("id", targID);
    $("div.style-sub-2").hide ();
    $('#' + tarID).show ();
} )
```

However, this will not change the ID of `test` after it's changed. You'll have to create a function to keep track of this but it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: How do I get it to show the third dropdown of days no matter which year or month is chosen?  http://jsfiddle.net/sloga/KdskX/15/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the pure JavaScript option:

`document.getElementById("test").id = "2013";`

I also noticed that:

```
$("div.style-sub-1 select").change ( function () {
    $("div.style-sub-2").hide ();
    document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("id", targID);
    $('#' + targID).show ();
} );
```

Is not going to trigger in your code as it is.  Did you mean to change the ID in the other `.change()` function?

Comment: I need the value from the selected dropdown from year to become the next dropdown div id. Are you saying that my syntax is not correct? change document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("id", targID); to document.getElementById("test").id = "value from selected dropdown";